# What is the most efficient way to manage a large set of lines in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, performance, conceptual

I am working on a simple CAD program which uses OpenGL to handle on-screen rendering. Every shape drawn on the screen is constructed entirely out of simple line segments, so even a simple drawing ends up processing thousands of individual lines.

What is the best way to communicate changes in this collection of lines between my application and OpenGL? Is there a way to update only a certain subset of the lines in the OpenGL buffers?

I'm looking for a conceptual answer here. No need to get into the actual source code, just some recommendations on data structure and communication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a simple approach such as using a display list (glNewList/glEndList)

The other option, which is slightly more complicated, is to use Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs - GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object). They have the advantage that they can be changed dynamically whereas a display list can not.

These basically batch all your data/transformations up and them execute on the GPU (assuming you are using hardware acceleration) resulting in higher performance.

Answer (score 7):

Vertex Buffer Objects are probably what you want. Once you load the original data set in, you can make modifications to existing chunks with `glBufferSubData()`.

If you add extra line segments and overflow the size of your buffer, you'll of course have to make a new buffer, but this is no different than having to allocate a new, larger memory chunk in C when something grows.

EDIT: A couple of notes on display lists, and why not to use them:

1. In OpenGL 3.0, display lists are deprecated, so using them isn't forward-compatible past 3.0 (2.1 implementations will be around for a while, of course, so depending on your target audience this might not be a problem)
2. Whenever you change anything, you have to rebuild the entire display list, which defeats the entire purpose of display lists if things are changed often.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're already doing this, but it's worth mentioning you should try to use GL_LINE_STRIP instead of individual GL_LINES if possible to reduce the amount of vertex data being sent to the card.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to try using a scene graph, some kind of hierarchical data structure for the lines/curves. If you have huge models, performance will be affected if you have plain list of lines. With a graph/tree structure you can check easily which items are visible and which are not by using bounding volumes. Also with a scenegraph you can apply transformation easily and reuse geometries.